# Why is quadratic programming used to the solve the support vector machine optimization problem instead of the analytic approach?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

**(Readers familiar with the mathematical framework of support vector machines may skip to "The problem")**

https://youtu.be/eHsErlPJWUU

This is a lecture video by Abu Mostafa on support vector machines, which I have been following. I'll summarize what he says so the reader may not have to go through the entire video:

Given: dataset $\{(x_1,y_1),\ldots,(x_n,y_n) \}$, where $x_i\in\mathbb{R}^d$ and $y_i\in\{-1,1\}$ for $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$

Need to find: $w\in\mathbb{R}^d$ and $b\in \mathbb{R}$ so that

1. $w^T x + b = 0$ is a separating hyperplane for the two classes of the dataset $+1,-1$, that is,
   $\text{sgn}(w^T x_i+b) = y_i $ where $\text{sgn}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a function such that $\text{sgn}(c) = 1$ if $c\geq 0$ and $\text{sgn}(c) = -1$ if $c< 0$.
2. Margin is symmetric and it is the maximum possible margin among all symmetric margins. That is,
   $\min_{\{i:y_i=1\}}\left|\frac{w^Tx_i+b}{||w||} \right| = \min_{\{i:y_i=-1\}}\left|\frac{w^Tx_i+b}{||w||} \right| = \max_{\{(\omega,\beta)\in\mathbb{R}^d\times\mathbb{R}:\min_{\{i:y_i=1\}}\left|\frac{\omega^Tx_i+\beta}{||\omega||} \right| = \min_{\{i:y_i=-1\}}\left|\frac{\omega^Tx_i+\beta}{||\omega||} \right|\}} \left(\min_{\{i:y_i=1\}}\left|\frac{\omega^Tx_i+\beta}{||\omega||} \right|\right) $

Trying to solve this, we arrive at the optimization problem after a few steps of simplification:

**The problem**

Minimize $||w||^2$ under the constraint that: $\min_{i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}}(w^T x_i+b) = 1$.

This constraint can be simplified to involve inequalities instead of a minimum, and then a modified version of Lagrange multipliers, called the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions can be used to finally obtain:

Minimize $\mathcal{L}(\alpha)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^ny_i y_j \alpha_i \alpha_j x_i x_j-\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i$ where $\mathcal{L}:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^n$ under the constraints:

1. $\alpha_i\geq 0 $ for every $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and
2. $\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i y_i = 0$.

Prof Mostafa then goes into how we resort to quadratic programming to solve this optimization problem.

However, it would seem to me one could much more easily solve this analytically in the following steps:

1. one could simply combine the second constraint of the summation with the original function to be optimized, $\mathcal{L}$ using Lagrange multipliers,
2. then use partial derivatives of $\mathcal{L}$ with respect to $\alpha_i$, $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and equate them to zero in order to get minimal points ignoring the first constraint,
3. and then finally, see whichever $\alpha_i$ are negative and change their values to $0$ in order to obey the first constraint while keeping the changes in the function to a minimum.

This procedure does not seem to me to have any possible difficulties in it other than the solution of $n$ simultaneous linear equations (linear because $\mathcal{L}$ is a quadratic function in each variable $\alpha_i$).

Is there a mistake I am making in any of the steps above?